# How to understand that response is fully downloaded if there is no Content-Length header

Tags: java, http, apache-httpcomponents

I'm trying to download a large file from an external server via HTTP. The response doesn't have `Content-Length` header, but has `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`.

In my java program I do the following:

1. Execute GET request and obtain response's InputStream
2. Read 10 MB from the input stream
3. Sleep for 100 seconds
4. Continue reading response (and there is actually more data, probably from different buffers - application, os, etc.)

The program finishes without throwing any exceptions. However, I know that it hasn't downloaded the whole file, because without sleeping response size would be much bigger.

I understand that the server can't wait for me infinitely, but is there a way for client to understand whether response was fully downloaded or not?

I use apache httpcomponents:httpclient v4.5.6.

```
    var client = HttpClients.custom()
        .disableContentCompression()
        .build();
    HttpGet request = createRequest();

    var response = client.execute(request);

    var is = response.getEntity().getContent();
    int count = 0;
    var os = new FileOutputStream("/tmp/test.gz");
    byte[] buffer = new byte[512];
    int read = is.read(buffer);
    while (read >= 0) {
      os.write(buffer, 0, read);
      read = is.read(buffer);
      count++;
      if (count == 10_000) {
        Thread.sleep(100_000);
      }
    }
    is.close();
    os.close();
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please post complete example source.

Comment: @JulianReschke, sorry, thought that the question is mostly about how http works, but I guess the exact code is important as well. Added.

Comment: AFAIU, your exit condition for the while loop is incorrect (0 means there may be more data).

Comment: @JulianReschke I agree, this place is not entirely correct. However, I know for sure that the loop exited after `read` was `-1`, because I had more logging around it. Anyway, I double checked, fixed the code to use `read >= 0` and the problem is still there.

Comment: Maybe the connections is timing out. Why do you have the sleep() there anyway?

Comment: This example is a very simplified version of the logic that I need to implement. Imagine that instead of sleep there is some business logic that needs to process the downloaded chunk. And not only once, but every N megabytes. 
I understand that the connection times out, it's not the question here. The question is how to programmatically understand that the connection timed out. Right now the program fails quietly.

Comment: Does this happen with multiple servers, or just a specific one?